# Python Regex for HTML File with Multi-Line Elements

Tags: python, regex

## Problem

I've converted a PDF into an HTML file using Adobe's built-in tools, but I'm struggling to write regex functions to capture the various data:

- **festival_name**
- **contact_name**
- **contact_email**
- **contact_phone**
- **notes**
- **festival_months**.

**MAIN ISSUE: Many of the HTML elements, along with the text between them, takes up multiple lines, so the regex will often skip.**

( **Note**: The HTML document contains a list of music festivals & their respective details )

## What I've tried

My current code works as follows:

1. Open the HTML file & loop through each line
2. Use a regular expression to find  tags with an inline-style of ( **style='color:#FF2500** )
3. Place the matches in a dictionary called ***festivalBlock{}*** in a key named *city*
4. Begin another regex from the current line searching for the ***festival_name***
5. Append the current *festivalBlock* to a dictionary called ***festivalList{}*** under a key named ***festivals***

#### HTML Screenshot & Excerpt:

[image]

```
<h1 style='margin-top:7.3pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:
61.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><a name=ALABAMA></a><a name="_bookmark0"></a>ALABAMA</h1>

<p class=MsoBodyText style='margin-top:.2pt'><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:
normal'><span style='font-size:35.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></b></p>

<h5 style='margin-left:61.0pt'><a name=Alabaster></a><a name="_bookmark1"></a><span
style='color:#FF2500'>Alabaster</span></h5>

<p class=MsoBodyText style='margin-top:.15pt'><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:
normal'><i style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'><span style='font-size:12.5pt;
mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></b></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:73.45pt;margin-bottom:
0in;margin-left:61.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:101%'><b
style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span style='font-size:14.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:
11.0pt;line-height:101%'>Takeoff Fest </span></b><a
href="mailto:interstellarginger@gmail.com"><span style='font-size:12.0pt;
mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:101%;color:blue'>interstellarginger@gmail.co</span></a><a
href="mailto:interstellarginger@gmail.com"><span style='color:blue'>m</span></a><span
style='color:blue'> </span>Festival Month(s): <i style='mso-bidi-font-style:
normal'>June<o:p></o:p></i></p>

<p class=MsoBodyText style='margin-top:.05pt'><i style='mso-bidi-font-style:
normal'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p>

<h5 style='margin-left:61.0pt'><a name=Albertville></a><a name="_bookmark2"></a><span
style='color:#FF2500'>Albertville</span></h5>

<p class=MsoBodyText style='margin-top:.4pt'><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:
normal'><i style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'><span style='font-size:12.5pt;
mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></b></p>

<h6 style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:34.05pt;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:
61.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:105%'>Albertville Main Street Music
Festival</h6>

<p class=MsoBodyText style='margin-top:.2pt;margin-right:73.45pt;margin-bottom:
0in;margin-left:61.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><a
href="mailto:pformby@cityofalbertville.com"><span style='color:windowtext;
text-decoration:none;text-underline:none'>pformby@cityofalbertville.com</span></a>
Festival Month(s):<i style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'>August<o:p></o:p></i></p>

<p class=MsoBodyText style='margin-top:.3pt'><i style='mso-bidi-font-style:
normal'><span style='font-size:12.5pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p>

<h6 style='margin-left:61.0pt'>Main Street Music Festival</h6>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:.2pt;margin-right:-.95pt;margin-bottom:
0in;margin-left:61.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:100%'><a
href="http://www.mainstreetmusicfestival.com/e%20ntertainment.html"><span
style='font-size:10.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:100%;color:blue'>http://www.mainstreetmusicfestival.com/e</span></a><span
style='font-size:10.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:100%;color:blue'>
</span><a href="http://www.mainstreetmusicfestival.com/e%20ntertainment.html"><span
style='font-size:10.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:100%;color:blue'>ntertainment.html</span></a><span
style='font-size:10.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:100%;color:blue'>
</span><a href="mailto:eventcoordinator@mainstreetmusicfestival.com"><span
style='color:windowtext;text-decoration:none;text-underline:none'>eventcoordinator@mainstreetmusicfestival.com</span></a>
<b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><i style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:100%'>Note: </span></i></b><i
style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:
11.0pt;line-height:100%'>Submissions open through June (online only).<o:p></o:p></span></i></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-left:61.0pt;line-height:13.2pt;mso-line-height-rule:
exactly'>Festival Month(s): <i style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'>August<o:p></o:p></i></p>

<p class=MsoBodyText style='margin-top:.35pt'><i style='mso-bidi-font-style:
normal'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p>

<h5 style='margin-left:61.0pt'><a name="Alexander_City"></a><a name="_bookmark3"></a><span
style='color:#FF2500'>Alexander City</span></h5>

<p class=MsoBodyText style='margin-top:.4pt'><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:
normal'><i style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'><span style='font-size:12.5pt;
mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></b></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:34.05pt;margin-bottom:
0in;margin-left:61.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:100%'><b
style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span style='font-size:14.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:
11.0pt;line-height:100%'>Alexander City Jazz Festival </span></b><a
href="http://www.alexcityjazzfest.com/get-involved.html256-397-1019"><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:100%;color:blue'>http://www.alexcityjazzfest.com/get-</span></a><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:100%;color:blue'>
</span><a href="http://www.alexcityjazzfest.com/get-involved.html256-397-1019"><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:100%;color:blue'>involved.html256-397-1019</span></a><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:100%;color:blue'>
</span><a href="mailto:info@alexcityjazzfest.com"><span style='color:blue'>info@alexcityjazzfest.com</span></a></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-left:61.0pt;line-height:13.65pt;mso-line-height-rule:
exactly'><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><i style='mso-bidi-font-style:
normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt'>Note: </span></i></b><i
style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:
11.0pt'>Online submission.<o:p></o:p></span></i></p>

<p class=MsoBodyText style='margin-top:.3pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:
0in;margin-left:61.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt'>Festival Month(s): <i
style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'>June<o:p></o:p></i></p>
```

#### Python Code:

```
import re
from re import search
import json
from collections import defaultdict
import os

f = open("./data/fairs-and-festivals-min.htm", "r", encoding="utf-8")

# Variables ...
cityList = {}
festivalList = {
    "festivals": []
}
file_pos = 0

for line in f:
    # [0] Prepare dictionary for festival data ...
    festivalBlock = {
        "city": "",
        "festivals": []
    }

    # [1] Find City w/ red text ...
    cityData = re.search(r"'color:(#FF2500)'", line)

    # Match was found ...
    if(cityData):

    # [2] Add city name to list ...

        # Strip extra HTML from city name ...
        city = re.findall(r"style='color:#FF2500'>(.*?)</span>", line)
        city = " ".join(city) # Convert city from list to string ...
        festivalBlock["city"] = city

        # if cityData.group(1) not in cityList:
        #     cityList[cityData.group(1)] = [city]
        # else:
        #     cityList[cityData.group(1)].append(city)


        """
            Festival Blocks - DATA STRUCTURE:

            "state": "Arizona",
            "city": "Alabaster",
            "festivals": [
                            {
                                "festival_name": "Hopkins Raspberry Festival",
                                "contact_name": "Lou Jean Gleason",
                                "contact_email": "loujean@raspberrycapital.com",
                                "contact_phone": "952-931-0878",
                                "notes": "Note: Online submission.",
                                "festival_months": "Festival Month(s): July"
                            },
                            {
                                "festival_name": "Hopkins Raspberry Festival",
                                "contact_name": "Lou Jean Gleason",
                                "contact_email": "loujean@raspberrycapital.com",
                                "contact_phone": "952-931-0878",
                                "notes": "Note: Online submission.",
                                "festival_months": "Festival Month(s): July"
                            }
                        ]
        """

    # [3] Find first festival in this city ... 

        # TODO: Look for multiple festivals within cities ...
        # Get Festival name (span or h6) | STOP AFTER FIRST MATCH ...
        festivalCount = 0 # iterator
        for cityLine in f:

            """ DEBUGGING CODE BELOW ... """
            # if(festivalCount >= 3):
            #     continue

            # Span version | Pattern 'line-height:xxx%'>festival_name</span>'
            festivalName = re.findall(r"line-height:([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)%'>(.*?)</span>", cityLine) 
            if(festivalName):
                festival = defaultdict(list)
                festival["festival_name"] = festivalName[0][2]
                festivalBlock["festivals"].append(festival)
                festivalCount += 1
                break
            else:
                regex = re.compile(r">(.*?)</h6>", re.DOTALL)
                festivalName = regex.findall(cityLine)

                if(festivalName): # Festival name wrapped in h6 | Ignore empty strings
                    print(festivalName)
                    unwantedPhrase = "Note"
                    if not unwantedPhrase in festivalName:
                    # if unwantedPhrase in festivalName: # Ignore unwanted text/phrases (i.e. Note:)
                        festival = defaultdict(list)
                        festival["festival_name"] = festivalName
                        festivalBlock["festivals"].append(festival)
                        
                        festivalCount += 1
                        break
                    break


    # [4] Append block to list of festivals ...
        festivalList["festivals"].append([festivalBlock])

        
        # [Z] Iterate file line position...
        file_pos += len(line)
    else:

        # [Z] Iterate file line position...
        file_pos += len(line)
        continue

    
                
# Print festivals to json file 
output = open("./data/festivals.json", "w")
output.write(json.dumps(festivalList))
output.close()
```

Aside from Python, I've tried *beautifying* the HTML document, *minifying* the HTML document, and even using jQuery.

## My Research

I've tried libraries such as ***Py2PDF***, ***PyQuery*** & ***html2str***, but regular expressions seem to be the most practical solution; considering the way the HTML document is poorly formatted.

## Question

How can I ensure that my regex methods don't skip HTML elements that extend beyond a single line?

Comment: Tip of the day: Use the Beautiful Soup library, _not_ regex, to parse HTML content.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you! Will it parse CSS and/or attributes? The HTML document doesn't have consistent classes or IDs, so I've got to rely on inline styles as differentiators

Comment: It returns the attributes to you.  It's up to you to decide what to do with the attribute values.